# How do I remove all users from an SPGroup object?

Tags: development, security, object-model

I have an SPGroup object populated, how can I remove all members from the group, so that essentially I start with a fresh group.

I can't delete and recreate it, so I need a way to work with the existing SharePoint group.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Take a look on [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spgroup.removeuser.aspx)

```
    foreach (SPUser user in group.Users)
    {
        group.RemoveUser(user);
    }
```

But be aware that you change this group for the whole site collection, if you have other site collections those won't be impacted by the modification of this group.

Comment: Won't this throw a modify collection exception?

Comment: I have tested it and it works.

Comment: Neat, was looking for this. I was afraid that this would in fact skip every other user due to the indexes changing as users get removed, as is the situation when removing groups for example. Tried it, and it worked fine. Nice solution Anatoly. =)

Comment: I'm not sure how this works since the collection is being modified directly. Is it because this is server code and it gets a new instance of the collection during each iteration? I know the CSOM version of this would not work.

Comment: @JL01 I believe this works because the `foreach()` call to the `Users` property creates a new SPUserCollection object and gets an enumerator to that collection. The `RemoveUser` call itself just gets the ID from the user object before calling its Users property (generating a new SPUserCollection) to delete the user by ID. It looks like each new SPUserCollection gets a copy of the data so you're not enumerating on the same collection you're modifying (and also creating n+1 SPUserCollection objects where n = number of users in group)

Answer (score 0):

```
   while (group.Users.Count > 0)
     {
        group.Users.Remove(group.Users[0]);
     }
```

This should remove all the users in the group for CSOM. 
Edit: It would be inefficient for SSOM, however.

Comment: I believe every call to .Users returns a new SPUserCollection so in this case you will create 3n+1 new collections (.Count(), .Remove(), [0]) where n is the number of users in the group (the +1 is the final check where .Count == 0).

Comment: Maybe with SSOM, but you believe that is the case in CSOM once the users are already loaded?

Comment: Ah, I was reading the question as specific to SSOM and my comment was related to that. I haven't used the CSOM but I do know they share some common implementation. I would expect CSOM to implement some caching or proxying to prevent excessive network chatter so I don't know the impact there.

Comment: Ah okay. You did confirm the answer to a question in my comment on the accepted answer though. That's an important clarification.